# Is there any potential problem when casting an int to enum when the int is greater than the number of possible values?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Is there any potential problem that I should be aware of when casting an int to enum when the int is greater than the number of possible values, say

Here is the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/686Gov8s1), which seems work well:) :

```
#include <iostream>
 
 int main()
 {
     enum Demo{NONE=0, OK, HEART, OTHERS, FULL}; 
     enum Demo demo = static_cast<enum Demo>(9);

     std::cout << static_cast<int>(demo) << std::endl;
     std::cout << (static_cast<int>(demo) == 9) << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, you risk UB, unless you explicitly specify the underlying type of the enum, or use `enum class` (which defaults to `: int` underlying type, unlike `enum`). [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) explains it

Comment: Do you include "Is unequal to all the enumerators" in "potencial problem"?

Comment: the number of possible values is not restricted by the enumerators but by the underlying type. The only problem to be aware of is wrong expectations ;) because the range of `Demo` is much more than what you think it is

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The valid values of `Demo` are `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`, despite its underlying type being `int`.

Comment: C++ enum is free to use underlying type that fits all enumerators. OTOH as value 9 has to fit into smallest integral type char, it looks OK.

Comment: Check the definition of `std::byte`. It's an `enum class` of `std::uint8_t` values, with no named values. The identifiers defined inside an `enum` just mark its **named** set of **values**. With `enum class`, you get stricter syntax, but semantics don't change(except for its `underlying_type`)